# How to do exhaustive type checking with enums in flowtype?

Tags: enums, flowtype, string-literals

I'm trying to add exhaustive type checking for my enums in **flowtype**. I expect this sort of code to work (and it does in TypeScript):

```
export const Unit = {
  Meter: "Meter",
  Feet: "Feet"
};
Object.freeze(Unit);
export type UnitEnum = $Enum<typeof Unit>;

export function shortName(unit: UnitEnum): string {
  switch (unit) {
    case Unit.Meter:
      return "m";
    case Unit.Feet:
      return "ft";
    default:
      (unit: empty);
      throw "Invalid unit";
  }
}
```

Unfortunatelly this line `(unit: empty)` fails with errors :

> Cannot cast unit to empty because:
> • string literal Feet [1] is incompatible with empty [2].
> • string literal Meter [1] is incompatible with empty [2].

I did some experimenting and this seems to work, i.e. replacing enum references by their values:

```
export function longName(unit: UnitEnum): string {
  switch (unit) {
    case "Meter":
      return "meter";
    case "Feet":
      return "feet";
    default:
      (unit: empty);
      throw "Invalid unit";
  }
}
```

But this just doesn't seem right as we should be able to use references to the `Unit` enum as we do in other languages.

**So is there a way to do this properly?**

---

I also tried to make sure that I have correct types on values of `Unit`, but that doesn't help:

```
export const Unit: {
  +Meter: "Meter",
  +Feet: "Feet"
} = {
  Meter: "Meter",
  Feet: "Feet"
};
Object.freeze(Unit);
export type UnitEnum = $Keys<typeof Unit>;
```

Comment: I think this is a know issue in flow and there are a lot of issues in the repo around string literals and switches. [This one](https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/6429) seems to come close to your problem here.

Comment: It's like the third time I come back to my own question to find out that this sort of basic thing doesn't work...